# Larmor Precession of a macroscopic number of electrons

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, precession

I know that there are some similiar questions out there, but I'm still quite puzzled by the following problem. Say i have a box full of interacting electrons ( I'm not sure if it would change anything if we take for example fermionic Atoms) and put that box in a homogeneous magnetic field B_z. Depending on the strength of the field I'll create an overpopulation of the spin state which is aligned parallel in field. I won't manage to have 100% alligned, due to Fermi statistics. If i made a mistake until now correct me, but here comes the actual question i want to ask.

If I apply an additional perpendicular(xy-Plane) AC-B field with a suitable frequency that matches the Larmor-Frequency, what exactly is going to happen?

I was taught that absorption of the RF field will "tilt" the Spin out of its equilibrium position by a certain angle. This angle depends on the power of the applied RF-Field. 
How can it be possible that i can tilt by any angle, if there are only 2 allowed states along the z-Axis?

Do I really change the magnetization of the box? Say if it was 70% aligned before the RF-Puls is it less afterwards?

When I start tilting, the Spins start precessing around the Strong B_z field, this Frequency is only dependent on the B-Field, not on the angle. 
Why do they even precess at first?